# Matlab: Converting a Cell with Double values to String

Tags: matlab

I need a command that converts `A={1 2 3}` to `A={'1' '2' '3'}`. In other words, I want the input `A={1 2 3}` to be converted into `{'1' '2' '3'}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one alternative using [`sprintfc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) (Undocumented helper function)

```
out = sprintfc('%d',cell2mat(A))
```

**Output:**

```
out = 

'1'    '2'    '3'
```

While `%d` refers integers, you might use `%.4f` (where .4 refers number of decimal digits after the decimal point) for floating point numbers.

**For Example,**

```
out = sprintfc('%.3f',cell2mat(A))
```

**Output:**

```
out = 

'1.000'    '2.000'    '3.000'
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could use something like this:

```
 B = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x), A, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

But I'm sure I'm missing a simpler way.

Comment: I don't think there's an easier way... I was thinking along the same lines.

Comment: Is it applicable for date-form values?

Comment: @SauloCarvalho indeed, assuming that A is a cell array of datetimes as numbers, such as you would get from the 'now' function, then you could replace 'num2str' with 'datestr' and this would work.